# Android Uploading apk first time with apk exapansion

Tags: android

I am uploading game with apk expansion.But when i upload the first apk it is not showing popup to expansion file upload,second time with updated version then it show the popup to upload the expansion file.

Let me know if anyone have solution for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en) of the Google developer console.

You have to upload a second APK to be able to add the expansion file.